# TimePicker from android examples not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make work this example from  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html ,
no errors while compiling - but when I press button - nothing happens. Complete silent. Why? Btw - I tried to put Log.d() in button click event and it works, but still no popup with timepicker.

Main.xml used "As is" from example

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestastestasActivity extends Activity {

      private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        mYear = year;
                        mMonth = monthOfYear;
                        mDay = dayOfMonth;
                        updateDisplay();
                    }
                };

    // updates the date we display in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     private TextView mDateDisplay;
        private Button mPickDate;

        private int mYear;
        private int mMonth;
        private int mDay;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            // capture our View elements
            mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
            mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

            // add a click listener to the button
            mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d ("Debug", "YO MAN");
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });

            // get the current date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // display the current date
            updateDisplay();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView android:text="@string/date_text" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="26px" 
    android:typeface="sans"></TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/date_button" 
    android:id="@+id/Button01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<TextView android:text="@string/time_text" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26px" 
    android:typeface="sans"></TextView>
<Button android:text="@string/time_button" 
    android:id="@+id/Button02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

datepickerlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/DatePicker01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

PickerViewSample.java

```
package com.sai.samples.views;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class PickerViewSample extends Activity {

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;
    private TextView dateDisplay;
    private Button pickDate;
    private int year, month, day;
    private TextView timeDisplay;
    private Button pickTime;
    private int hours, min;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        pickDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        pickDate.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }

        });

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDate();

        timeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        pickTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);

        pickTime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

        hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        updateTime();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        timeDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(min));

    }

    private void updateDate() {
        dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append('-')
                .append(month + 1).append('-').append(year));

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = 
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                year = yr;
                month = monthOfYear;
                day = dayOfMonth;
                updateDate();
            }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hours = hourOfDay;
                min = minute;
                updateTime();
            }

    };
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListener, hours, min, false);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the reference of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722438/issues-working-with-two-datetime-picker/8722521#8722521). I hope it will helps you.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing this part:

```
@Overrideprotected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```